# Can JavaFX deal with cyclic property binding graphs?

Tags: binding, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Let's consider three JavaFX properties: A B C.

Now let's bind them bidirectionally into a triangle (A-B, B-C, A-C).

Now let's imagine that we modify the value of A.

Does this lead to problems (e.g. infinite recursion)?

Can JavaFX deal with such cyclic binding graphs? If yes, how does it do that ?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try it...

```
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;


public class CyclicPropertyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntegerProperty x = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
        IntegerProperty y = new SimpleIntegerProperty(1);
        IntegerProperty z = new SimpleIntegerProperty(2);

        x.addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.printf("x changed from %d to %d %n", oldValue, newValue));
        y.addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.printf("y changed from %d to %d %n", oldValue, newValue));
        z.addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.printf("z changed from %d to %d %n", oldValue, newValue));

        x.bindBidirectional(y);
        y.bindBidirectional(z);
        z.bindBidirectional(x);

        x.set(1);
    }

}
```

The listeners are only notified if the value of the property changes. When x is set to 1, this results in y being set to 1, which results in z being set to 1. These fire the listeners. Since z has changed, this results (at least conceptually) in x being set to 1, but since it's already 1, no listeners are notified and hence the cycle terminates.